# Rxjava single element buffer

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a case that, there is a object which publish object in the random time, I want to collect it by per-second into the buffer and filter by some strategy such as max score to make sure only one object in the buffer per-second.

```
subject
    .buffer(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .filter {
        isNotEmpty
    }
    .doOnNext {
        // I get all object in the one second
        // That waste too much memory, the non-max object shouldn't be put into the buffer
        _.asScala.max(byScore)
    }
    .ignoreElements
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io)
    .subscribe
```

This code will hold all object in one second and return to me.

Thas is not what I want.

Is any solution there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following version of the `buffer` operator:

```
.buffer(long timespan, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler, int count,
       Callable<U> bufferSupplier,
       boolean restartTimerOnMaxSize)
```

It allows you to define your custom `bufferSupplier` - collection used to store buffered values. You can then create your custom version of the collection, where you store at max one item and, in our case, replace existing value if new, bigger, come:

```
class SingleItemMaxCollection : ArrayList<Long>() {

    override fun add(element: Long): Boolean {
        return when {
            size == 1 && get(0) < element -> { super.set(0, element); true }
            size == 0 -> { super.add(element); true }
            else -> false
        }
    }
}
```

The demonstration, how can you use it on some mocked data (items emitted every 400 ms):

```
class SO65020891 {

    private fun dataProvider() = Observable.just(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)
        .concatMap { Observable.just(it).delay(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) }

    private fun getCollection(): () -> SingleItemMaxCollection = { SingleItemMaxCollection() }

    fun getBufferedMax(): Observable<Long> {
        return dataProvider()
            .buffer(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.computation(), 2, getCollection(), false)
            .filter { it.isNotEmpty() }
            .map { it[0] }
    }
}
```

And finally, some verification:

```
class SO65020891Test {

    @Test
    fun maxEmittedValuesReturnedWithinWindows() {
        val tested = SO65020891()

        val values = tested.getBufferedMax().blockingIterable().toList()

        assertEquals(listOf(2L, 4L, 6L), values)
    }
}
```